# Syncfusion Essential Studio in Azure WebApp (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, syncfusion

when I publish my application on Azure as WEBAPP, it loads everything correctly but I do not see the components of Essential Studio such as: PDFViewer, Menu, MarkEdit etc. but in the DOM Explorer of Edge I still see the correct scripts of Essential Studio.

How can i solve this problem?

(The application is publish on Visual Studio 2017 (ASP.NET MVC))

Thank you.

Comment: I guess, it might be rendering in the unobtrusive mode, please check this out https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/unobtrusive

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not include the required scripts or themes for rendering the control. Make sure that **ScriptManager** is included in *_layout.cshtml* page for rendering the controls, if unobtrusive mode is set to false in web.config file.

If unobtrusive mode is enabled, make sure that ejUnobtrusive.js script is included for rendering the control. Once the previous steps are ensured, now check whether your application run as expected in local before publishing.

If the application runs fine then make sure that there no compilation errors after publishing. Take a moment to look at the [Deployment of ASP.NET MVC Syncfusion controls to Azure](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7910/deployment-of-asp-net-mvc-syncfusion-controls-to-azure) KB article for more information. If you face any compilation errors or console errors, provide us the details on the issue along with screenshots or video. It will help us provide solution.

Comment: This answer is copied and pasted from my thread opened in the syncfusion community....